# powershell test connection for all port

Tags: powershell

If you had to test port 389, 636, 3268, and 3269 on over 300 machines as quickly as possible using PowerShell, how would you do it? Is PowerShell the right answer for this?

need output like below:-

### Hostname     389     636   443

Server 1     Pass   Pass   Pass
Server 2     Pass   Pass   Pass

Answer (score 3):

In PowerShell 7.0+:

```
"example.com","example.net","example.org" `
| ForEach-Object { 
    $computer = $_
    $ports = 389,636,3268,3269
    Write-Output $computer
    foreach ($port in $ports) {
        Write-Output $port
        Test-Connection -ComputerName $computer -TcpPort $port
    }
}
```

Will output:

```
example.com
389
False
636
False
3268
False
3269
False
example.net
389
False
636
False
3268
False
3269
False
example.org
389
False
636
False
3268
False
3269
False
```

Alternatively, in Windows PowerShell 5.1:

```
"example.com","example.net","example.org" `
| ForEach-Object { 
    $computer = $_
    $ports = 389,636,3268,3269
    Write-Output $computer
    foreach ($port in $ports) {
        Write-Output $port
        Test-NetConnection -ComputerName $computer -Port $port
    }
}
```

> as quickly as possible
> (...)
> Is PowerShell the right answer for this?

If by *as quickly as possible* you mean *shortest execution time*, then PowerShell is most definitely **NOT** the right answer. It'll do the job, but there are faster languages out there.

Comment: Would you not use [`Foreach-Object -Parallel`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/powershell-foreach-object-parallel-feature/) in your PS v7 code?

Comment: $comp = "abc", "xyz"
  $ports = "389","636","53"

foreach ($port in $ports) {
      Write-Output $port
      Test-NetConnection -computername $comp -Port $port |Out-String
      }

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler Absolutely should have! However, a [better answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69986266/2165530) using [https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/powershell-foreach-object-parallel-feature/](`Foreach-Object -Parallel`) was already supplied by [doug-maurer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4085331/doug-maurer). Hence, upvoting and leaving mine as is.

Answer (score 1):

This is tested in Powershell 7.2

```
$hostlist = 'Server1','Server2','Server3','Server4'

$portlist = 389, 636, 3268, 3269

$syncedht = [HashTable]::Synchronized(@{})

$hostlist | ForEach-Object -Parallel {

    $ht = $using:syncedht
    $ht[$_] = [ordered]@{Name=$_}
    $timeout = 500

    $using:portlist | ForEach-Object -Parallel {

        $ht = $using:ht
        $obj = New-Object System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient
        $ht[$using:_].$_ = ('Fail','Pass')[$obj.ConnectAsync($Using:_, $_).Wait($using:timeout)]

    } -ThrottleLimit 8

    [PSCustomObject]$ht[$_]

} -ThrottleLimit 32 -OutVariable results
```

You can increase the ThrottleLimit and can pipe it straight to `Export-Csv`

Comment: doesnt work for me

Comment: "doesn't work for me" doesn't tell anyone anything.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use PowerShell to run [NMap](https://nmap.org/download.html).

```
nmap.exe -p 389,636,3268,3269 -iL computers.txt
```

(Command line taken from [this site](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/nmap-scan-open-ports) )

Answer (score -1):

Create a nested loop that scans the desired ports against a list of machines:

```
# machines to scan
$comps = "abc", "xyz" 
# ports to scan
$ports = "389","636","53"
# iterate machines
foreach ($comp in $comps) {
    #iterate ports
    foreach ($port in $ports) { 
        Write-Output $port 
        Test-NetConnection -computername $comp -Port $port |
        Out-String 
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).